How to pass modular styles through props in React?
I have a component:
import React from 'react';
import s from './SectionsTitle.module.css';

const SectionsTitle = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.styleTitle}>
      {props.whiteFraction}<span{props.redFraction}</span> 
    </div>
  );
};

export default SectionsTitle;

I pass styleTitle through props from the parent component:
<SectionsTitle styleTitle='s.SectionsTitle' /> 

Is it possible to pass s.SectionsTitle through props somehow? It doesn't work for me this way

just pass "SectionsTitle" and <div className={s[props.styleTitle]}>

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-acrfwt?file=src%2FApp.js

You can pass the class name directly as a string through props like this: . This will correctly apply the CSS module class.

To pass s.SectionsTitle through props, you need to pass it as a string without quotes. The way you're attempting to use s.SectionsTitleas a string in your parent component won't work because it's not being evaluated as an object property. Instead, you should pass the class name directly as a prop.
In parent component:
<SectionsTitle styleTitle={s.SectionsTitle} whiteFraction="White" redFraction="Red" />

In child:
return (
        <div className={props.styleTitle}>
          {props.whiteFraction}<span>{props.redFraction}</span> 
        </div>
      );

